Getting error while creating calender with Qt 6.6.0 (QtCreator 13.0.0 ) that "MonthGrid is not a type"
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls.Windows

ApplicationWindow {
   width: 400
   height: 400

   GridLayout {
       columns: 2

       DayOfWeekRow {
           locale: grid.locale

           Layout.column: 1
           Layout.fillWidth: true
       }

       WeekNumberColumn {
           month: grid.month
           year: grid.year
           locale: grid.locale

           Layout.fillHeight: true
       }

       MonthGrid {
           id: grid
           month: Calendar.December
           year: 2015
           locale: Qt.locale("en_US")

           Layout.fillWidth: true
           Layout.fillHeight: true
       }
   }
}

.pro file
QT += quick

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

I am using above code to create calender in Qt 6.6.0 (QtCreator 13.0.0) but i am getting below errors that
'MonthGrid' is not a type
'WeekNumberColumn' is not a type
'DayOfWeekRow'is not a type.
I am not getting how to resolve this issue? Do i need to add anything extra in .pro file?
please guide me

Typo: add import QtQuick.Controls

And also add: QT += quickcontrols2

"Qt13.0.0"?!? What year do you live in?

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-index.html

@eyllanesc : I am still facing same issue after adding import and QT += quickcontrols2

@musicamante: sorry its QtCreator 13.0.0

Try with QtQuick.Controls instead of QtQuick.Controls.Windows import as @eyllanesc said. The documentation says that if a control isn't present in Windows style it will fallback to Fusion style, but this doesn't contain MonthGrid either.
